# Typescript AMD module Error (Module has not yet been loaded for context)

Tags: typescript, amd

I have the following Typescript file

```
/// <reference path="../../_references.ts" />
var app = require("modules/app");
var spactrl = require("controllers/spactrl");

var main = function (app: ng.IModule) {
    app.config(function ($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/", { controller: "HomeCtrl", templateUrl:"/spa/template/greet" });
    });
}
export = main;
```

but when I compile this into AMD, I get this output

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    /// <reference path="../../_references.ts" />
    var app = require("modules/app");
    var spactrl = require("controllers/spactrl");

    var main = function (app) {
        app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when("/", { controller: "HomeCtrl", templateUrl: "/spa/template/greet" });
        });
    };

    return main;
});
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

This results an error of **'Module name "modules/app" has not been loaded yet for context: _'**

Going through requirejs's docs http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

It looks like the generated file should either have my required "modules/app" or get rid of the dependency array all together.

Is there a work around for this? or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked through your code and you are trying to load js modules via require calls. E.g. :

https://github.com/odytrice/RequireAngular/blob/dev/RequireAngular/Scripts/app/modules/app.ts

```
require("angular-route");
require("angular-resource");
require("angular-animate");
```

This will not work since TypeScript does not know about these require calls and cannot add this to the `define` section. To tell typescript about this you need to use the `/// <amd-dependency`

PS: I have a video on the subject : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AGQpv0MKsA&hd=1

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of working with AMD modules in TypeScript is to use `import` statements, as per the following:

```
import ng = require("pathto/ng");
import app = require("modules/app");
import spactrl = require("controllers/spactrl");

var main = function (app: ng.IModule) {
    app.config(function ($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/", { controller: "HomeCtrl", templateUrl:"/spa/template/greet" });
    });
}
export = main;
```

When you compile this using the `--module amd` flag, it will generate the nested `require` calls with your code placed inside as a callback.

Comment: I tried that and it just removed the import statements but did not add those dependencies to the dependencies array

Comment: define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    var main = function (app) {
        app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when("/", { controller: "HomeCtrl", templateUrl: "/spa/template/greet" });
        });
    };
    
    return main;
});
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map